# Express sub-query in SELECT in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, cakephp

Abstracting as much as possible, I want to perform:

```
select id,complicatedCalculation as geodistance from User join others having geodistance < 100;
```

In CakePHP 2.x.  The actual query uses aggregation so we do need *having*.  This all works when the database is MySQL because that database accepts a column reference in the *having* clause.  We are now moving to Postgres which more rigidly implements the SQL standard and reports that `geodistance` does not exist.

The solution in SQL is to write the instruction as

```
select * from (select id, complicatedCalculation as geodistance from User join others) as sub where geodistance < 100;
```

But I can't see how to express that sub-query in Cake.  My best attempt so far is

```
$db = $this->User->getDataSource();
$core = [ 'fields' => [ 'id', 'complicatedCalculation as geodistance' ],
        'table' => $db->fullTableName($this->User),
        'join' => (others) ]
$sub_query = $db->buildStatement($core, $this->User);
$result = $this->User->find('all', [
        'fields' => [ 'id', 'geodistance' ],
        'table' => $db->expression($sub_query),
        'alias' => 'zzz',  // not used but PGSQL requires it.
        'conditions' => [ 'geodistance <=' => 100 ]
    ]);
```

but this produces the following SQL (abstracted) reported in the logs as an error:

```
SELECT "User"."id" AS "User__id", complicatedCalculation as geodistance FROM "public"."users" AS "User" LEFT JOIN (others) WHERE "geodistance" <= 100
```

so my attempt to make CakePHP use an expression as a table is not working.  Can I make it do so?

Answers proposing to upgrade to a current version of Cake are not acceptable.  If there's no other way, we'll just use `query()`.

Comment: Why using HAVING when you don't use an aggregate, nor grouping by anything. A plain WHERE should be enough. Unless complicatedCalculation is actually an aggregate function, then you could create this aggregate function in PostgreSQL using CREATE AGGREGATE. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html

Comment: Sorry, I abstracted too much.  The actual query does use aggregation.  I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is better.  Possibly they will be executed exactly the same.  Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

The real problem is that `geodistance` must be computed for every row, and there is no simple way to speed that up.

Here are 5 approaches

; yours is equivalent to the first (worst) one: [*Find Nearest*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql) .

Better is to use a `SPATIAL` index.  That will require changing the way the data is stored.

Another pretty-good way is to establish a "bounding box" and then have 2 indexes.

Both alternatives are discussed in that link.

Your query is "find all within 100".  The link talks about "find the closest N within 100".

Comment: Thanks but you're not answering the question I asked.  Obviously there must be a geodistance calculation for each row but I want create an alias for the result of the calculation so that I can use it twice:  once for the SQL selection (and ordering in fact but that's not relevant here) and secondly to pass back to the caller for further calculation, display or whatever.

Comment: Aggregation could add serious delays -- depending on the details.  Let's see both the generated SQL and the `EXPLAINs`.